# Admin menu for client, each menu for each content type

Tags: 7, routes, users

I want to create a admin interface for my client. For now, if my client wants to add an article, he needs to click *Content*, *Add content*, and select *Article* as content type; at the end, he can create a new node. This is not user-friendly.

I want to have *Article*, *Photo*, and *Video* as menu link in the Admin menu. If the user clicks on *Article*, it will show the list of all the articles list; I don't need to use the "type filter" to filter the content type, as users will click on the *Add* link in this list view directly, to add a node of each content type.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Since you just need a few links, I would use the Shortcut module which is a Drupal 7 core module. The documentation on this is pretty good: https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/shortcut.

You can configure under user permissions whether the user can edit the menu themselves or not. You can have different shortcut menus for different users.

Out of the box, you can only have 7 shortcuts on the shortcut bar at one time. There appears to be a patch for this, but I haven't tried it yet myself: https://drupal.org/node/682000#comment-6493066

However, to display the shortcut toolbar, it appears you have to expose the Admin toolbar to that user. You can make the admin toolbar pretty minimal by just giving the tool bar and create content permissions to the user.

If you really don't want to expose the admin toolbar to this user at all, then you might want to go with a menu block that only this user sees (set under block config>Roles). Your user would need to be given a unique role for this (which other users are not given). This assumes you have the Menu, Block and Menu Block modules installed.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [Administration Views module](https://drupal.org/project/admin_views)
This module override standard content list to configurable views.
In next step, you can make individual view for even content type

You can make menu list, whether provided all required functional.